# ¿Cuál es el error en mi codigo de python para crear una calculadora?

Tags: python

Quería saber si me pueden ayudar a identificar la causa de que no abra mi calculadora, lo que pasa es que al momento de iniciarlo desde la *cmd* me lanza un error y pues no me arranca, entonces pues me gustaría que analizaran el código y me dijeran en que falle, si tienen algún otro consejo que me pueda ayudar, pues bienvenido sea, no se si falten " , " o algo este generando error intente analizar una posible falla pero la verdad no pude solucionar nada.

**a continuación les mostraré mi código**

```py
from tkinter import *

boton = ""

def digito(num):

    global boton

    boton = boton + str(num)

    calculo.set(boton)


def igual():

    try:

        global boton

        total = str(eval(boton))

        calculo.set(total)

        boton = ""
    
    except:

        calculo.set(" error ")


def limpiar():

    calculo.set("")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    ventana = tk()


        ventana.configure(background="light green")
        
        ventana.title("Calculadora de Royver v1.0")
        
        ventana.geometry("195x224")
        

        calculo = StringVar()

        datos = Entry(ventana, textvariable=calculo)

        datos.grid(columspan=10, ipadx=50)

        

        boton7 = Button(ventana, text=' 7 ', fg='black', bg='white',
                        
                 command=lambda: digito(7), height=2, width=5)

        boton7.grid(row=2, column=0)
        
        boton8 = Button(ventana, text=' 8 ', fg='black',bg='white',

                 command=lambda: digito(8), height=2, width=5)

        boton8.grid(row=2, column=1)

        boton9 = Button(ventana, text=' 9 ', fg='black',bg='white',

                 command=lambda: digito(9), height=2, width=5)

        boton9.grid(row=2, column=2)

        boton4 = Button(ventana, text=' 4 ', fg='black',bg='white',

                 command=lambda: digito(4), height=2, width=5)

        boton4.grid(row=3, column=0)

        boton5 = Button(ventana, text=' 5 ', fg='black', bg='white',

                 command=lambda: digito(5), height=2, width=5)

        boton5.grid(row=3, column=1)

        boton6 = Button(ventana, text=' 6 ', fg='black', bg='white',

                 command=lambda: digito(6), height=2, width=5)
            
        boton6.grid(row=3, column=2)

        boton1 = Button(ventana, text=' 1 ', fg='black', bg='white',

                 command=lambda: digito(1), height=2, width=5)

        boton1.grid(row=4, column=0)

        boton2 = Button(ventana, text=' 2 ', fg='black', bg='white',
                 
                 command=lambda: digito(2), height=2, width=5)

        boton2.grid(row=4, column=1)

        boton3 = Button(ventana, text= ' 3 ', fg='black', bg='white',
                 
                 command=lambda: digito(3), height=2, width=5)

        boton3.grid(row=4, column=2)

        suma = Button(ventana, text= ' + ', fg='black', bg='white',
               
               command=lambda: digito(+), height=2, width=5)

        suma.grid(row=3, column=3)

        boton0 = Button(ventana, text=' 0 ', fg='black', bg='white',
                 
                 command=lambda: digito(0), height=2, width=5)

        boton0.grid(row=5, column=0)

        resta = Button(ventana, text=' - ', fg='black', bg='white',

                command=lambda: digito("-"), height=2, width=5)

        resta.grid(row=2, column=3)

        decimal = Button(ventana, text=' . ', fg='black', bg='white',

                  command=lambda: digito("."), height=2, width=5)

        decimal.grid(row=5, column=1)

        resultado = Button(ventana, text=' = ', fg='black', bg='white',

                    command=lambda: digito("="), height=2, width=5)

        resultado.grid(row=5, column=3)

        divide = Button(ventana, text=' / ', fg='black', bg='white',

                 command=lambda: digito("/"), height=2, width=5)

        divide.grid(row=4, column=3)

        multiplica = Button(ventana, text=' * ', fg='black', bg='white',

                     command=lambda: digito("*"), height=2, width=5)

        multiplica.grid(row=5, column=2)

        limpiar = Button(ventana, text='limpiar', fg='black', bg='white',

                  command=limpiar, height=2, width=5)

        limpiar.grid(row=6, column='1')



  ventana.mainloop()
```

Por cierto, ejecuté el código con el que me ayude y ese si sirvió y según yo tengo todo igual, entonces la verdad no se

Comment: Edite y eliminé el contenido no relevante así como aquello que hacía lucir a tu pregunta basada en opiniones y generaría su cierre, centra tu pregunta siempre en un problema puntual

Comment: @Elroyver puedes mejorar el título de tu publicación? En SO hay miles de preguntas que podrían tener exactamente el mismo título que el tuyo.

Comment: Puedes por favor poner el error que te arroja.

Comment: Copié y ejecuté tu código y tiene varios errores. 1- Esta mal indentado. 2- En el `command` del botón `+` espera un carácter `'+'` y lo estas pasando sin comillas. 3- La clase no se llama `tk()` se llama `Tk()` 4- Se escribe `columnspan` y tienes `columspan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copie, revise y edite tu código.

el primer error que encontré fue que cuando estas creando la raíz de tu aplicación estas llamando a la clase `Tk()` de una forma errónea.

```
ventana = tk() # esto esta mal

ventana = Tk() # esto esta bien, la 't' es con mayúscula
```

el otro error que encontré es que a tu botón suma le estas pasando el operador '+' sin comillas, y esto genera otro error.

```
suma = Button(ventana, text= ' + ', fg='black', bg='white',          
              command=lambda: digito(+), height=2, width=5) # mal

suma = Button(ventana, text= ' + ', fg='black', bg='white',            
            command=lambda: digito("+"), height=2, width=5) # bien
```

el tercer error es el posicionamiento que le estas dando a tu entry

```
datos = Entry(ventana, textvariable=calculo)
datos.grid(columspan=10, ipadx=50) # mal

datos = Entry(ventana, textvariable=calculo)
datos.grid(row=0, column=0) # bien
```

este es tu código pero un poco mas ordenado, con los widgets mejor posicionados y funcionando, ahora te toca a ti hacer que las funciones devuelvan el resultado esperado.

[tutorial de grid](https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/29713/grid--)

```
from tkinter import *

ventana = Tk()
ventana.configure(background="light green")
ventana.title("Calculadora de Royver v1.0")
ventana.geometry("180x224")

boton = ""

def limpiar():
    calculo.set("")

def digito(num):

    global boton

    boton = boton + str(num)

    calculo.set(boton)


def igual():

    try:

        global boton

        total = str(eval(boton))

        calculo.set(total)

        boton = ""
    
    except:

        calculo.set(" error ")


calculo = StringVar()

datos = Entry(ventana, textvariable=calculo)
datos.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=N+S+W+E)

boton7 = Button(ventana, text=' 7 ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito(7), height=2, width=5)
boton7.grid(row=1, column=0)

boton8 = Button(ventana, text=' 8 ', fg='black',bg='white', command=lambda: digito(8), height=2, width=5)
boton8.grid(row=1, column=1)

boton9 = Button(ventana, text=' 9 ', fg='black',bg='white', command=lambda: digito(9), height=2, width=5)
boton9.grid(row=1, column=2)

boton4 = Button(ventana, text=' 4 ', fg='black',bg='white', command=lambda: digito(4), height=2, width=5)
boton4.grid(row=1, column=3)

boton5 = Button(ventana, text=' 5 ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito(5), height=2, width=5)
boton5.grid(row=2, column=0)

boton6 = Button(ventana, text=' 6 ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito(6), height=2, width=5)
boton6.grid(row=2, column=1)

boton1 = Button(ventana, text=' 1 ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito(1), height=2, width=5)
boton1.grid(row=2, column=2)

boton2 = Button(ventana, text=' 2 ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito(2), height=2, width=5)
boton2.grid(row=2, column=3)

boton3 = Button(ventana, text= ' 3 ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito(3), height=2, width=5)
boton3.grid(row=3, column=0)

suma = Button(ventana, text= ' + ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito("+"), height=2, width=5)
suma.grid(row=3, column=1)

boton0 = Button(ventana, text=' 0 ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito(0), height=2, width=5)
boton0.grid(row=3, column=2)

resta = Button(ventana, text=' - ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito("-"), height=2, width=5)
resta.grid(row=3, column=3)

decimal = Button(ventana, text=' . ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito("."), height=2, width=5)
decimal.grid(row=4, column=0)

resultado = Button(ventana, text=' = ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito("="), height=2, width=5)
resultado.grid(row=4, column=1)

divide = Button(ventana, text=' / ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito("/"), height=2, width=5)
divide.grid(row=4, column=2)

multiplica = Button(ventana, text=' * ', fg='black', bg='white', command=lambda: digito("*"), height=2, width=5)
multiplica.grid(row=4, column=3)

limpiar = Button(ventana, text='limpiar', fg='black', bg='white', command=limpiar, height=2, width=5)
limpiar.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=N+S+W+E)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: El error de la ultima es que se escribe `columnspan` y tiene `columspan`

Comment: correcto por eso lo edite en el código grande y le envié un link de un tutorial del método grid para pueda ver las propiedades y la sintaxis de todo.